# How to Extract AST of given Typescript code using the open source Typescript compiler code?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

As it is known that Typescript is completely opensource now. which is available at [Tyescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript). I am building an application that will get Typescript code as input and give output the AST of the given code. Provide me a proper way to extract this AST(Abstract Syntax Tree) of input Typescript code rather than comppliling it and converting it into Javascript.

Comment: You could also inspect the AST in a more visual way in https://astexplorer.net/

Answer (score 6):

Basic code:

```
const fileNames = ["C:\\MyFile.ts"];
const compilerOptions: ts.CompilerOptions = {
    // compiler options go here if any...
    // look at ts.CompilerOptions to see what's available
};
const program = ts.createProgram(fileNames, compilerOptions);
const typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
const sourceFiles = program.getSourceFiles();

sourceFiles.filter(f => /MyFile\.ts$/.test(f.fileName)).forEach(sourceFile => {
    ts.forEachChild(sourceFile, node => {
        const declaration = node as ts.Declaration;
        if (declaration.name) {
            console.log(declaration.name.getText());
        }
    });
});
```

So if you provided that with a `C:\MyFile.ts` like:

```
class MyClass {}
interface MyInterface {}
```

It would output `MyClass` and `MyInterface`.

Figuring out everything beyond what I've just shown is a lot of work. It might be more beneficial for you to look at and/or help contribute to [this work in progress](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-simple-ast).

Comment: I did not understand the area {/* compiler options go here*/}. Please explain what is its mean?

Comment: @AhmedRaza compiler options like what is found in tsconfig.json. The type will be `ts.CompilerOptions`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Please share any example related to it.

Comment: @AhmedRaza I updated it with a working example, but you will have to figure out the rest. It's a lot of work.

Comment: yes its good but it is also give the same output if i declare any variable or function in class and interface. How can i extract the variables and functions in class.

Comment: @AhmedRaza you will have to do some investigative work on the output to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript compiler doesn't support it but you can do it using recast and babylon@next. Although you will have to trust in the syntax defined by these technologies for representing TypeScript code AST and that they will keep up to date - since TypeScript has new language features release by release (short period of time) - is not like other languages (JavaScript) where you have well defined versions and released in a standard - so if your users start using new language features these technologies (mostly babylon) should keep up to date:

```
// npm install recast babylon@next
const source = `
interface I {
  color: string
}
class C implements I{
  color: string='blue'
}
`
const recast = require('recast')
const tsParser = require("recast/parsers/typescript")
const ast = recast.parse(source, {
  parser: tsParser
});
console.log(`
CODE: 

${source}

AST: 

${JSON.stringify(ast)}
`);
```