# How to Generate AST of Typescript

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, tsc

I need to build an application that gets input of Typescript code and give output the AST of the given input code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Extract AST of given Typescript code using the open source Typescript compiler code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505533/how-to-extract-ast-of-given-typescript-code-using-the-open-source-typescript-com)

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need the Typescript's grammar.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14529028/3740935) is a valid starting point for this.

> Since typescript is a strict superset of Ecmascript 5 (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), you could exend any ecmascript bnf with syntax definitions from the Typescript spec.
>
> A starting point could be: http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1153976512034/ecmascriptA3.g

After you have the right grammar this work is almost done.
You can use a parser/lexer like [JavaCup](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/examples.php#xml) for generate your abstract syntax tree.

Comment: Except using any external lexer /parser I want to get the AST from [Typescript Opensource compiler code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript).